# How to start a nodejs child process in separate cmd window or terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to start a nodejs child process in a separate *console* window rather than of listening to its data event.

as per the [Documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached)

with the detached option, the child supposes to have its own *console* window but it's not happening.

my code in main.js

```
const { spawn} = require("child_process");

var child = spawn("node", ["./count.js"], {
    detached: true,
    stdio: 'ignore'
});
```

in the count.js file, I have

```
console.log(`running in child process with PID ${process.pid})
```

Comment: Are you using Windows? The `detached` option will only open a new console window on Windows.

Comment: yes i am using windows 10

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've found to work on windows 10 is to spawn a separate cmd.exe process entirely:

```js
const { spawn} = require("child_process");

var child = spawn("cmd.exe", ["/c", "node", "count.js"], {
    detached: true,
    stdio: 'ignore'
});
```

Also be sure to add some delay to your child process so it doesn't quit before you can see it:

```js
console.log(`running in child process with PID ${process.pid}`);

// wait 5 seconds before closing
setTimeout(() => true, 5000);
```

And finally, if you want your child window to be entirely independent from the parent (stays open even when the parent closes), you should unref it after you spawn it:

```js
child.unref();
```